# How can i access the number of evaluations in my Pymoo result object?

Tags: python, optimization, pymoo

When minimizing a Pymoo test problem i want to get the number of evaluations **n_eval**. Calling minimize with verbose option prints out this display information:

```
n_gen  |  n_eval  | n_nds  |      igd      |       gd     
==========================================================
     1 |      100 |      1 |  0.1852373892 |  0.1852373892
     2 |      200 |      1 |  0.0594274085 |  0.0594274085
     3 |      300 |      1 |  0.0148930530 |  0.0148930530
     4 |      400 |      1 |  0.0000231350 |  0.0000231350
     5 |      500 |      1 |  0.0000231350 |  0.0000231350
```

I expected to get access to a variable n_eval in the result object. I have not found any documentation on that online so far.

---UPDATE---

So, I found a solution which is too resource intensive imo as it requires saving the whole algorithm history, but it works for now.
I set the attribute `saveHistory=True` in the minimize method. Then I can read out the number of evaluations **n_eval** from the result object using **n_gen** and **n_pop**.

```py
    n_gen = len(result.history)
    n_pop = result.algorithm.pop_size
    n_eval = n_gen * n_pop
```

See the documentation for more info:
[pymoo - Minimize](https://pymoo.org/interface/minimize.html)

> save_history: A boolean value representing whether a snapshot of the algorithm should be stored in each iteration. If enabled, the Result object contains the history.

Comment: I also would like to know how to do this...

Comment: Colton please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pymoo, you can access the `n_eval` attribute of an optimization result object to get the number of function evaluations performed during the optimization process.

Assuming you have already performed an optimization using Pymoo, and have stored the result in a variable `result`, you can access the `n_eval` attribute as follows:

```
n_evaluations = result.algorithm.evaluator.n_eval
```